# SQL Server Composite Keys with One Identity Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, composite-key

I have several tenants who each have a database containing a table with a primary key `FooId`:

```
FooId
-----
1
2
3
...
```

Now I need to roll up all of the databases into a single multi-tenanted database, so I want to add a `TenantId` column to my table like so:

```
TenantId | FooId
---------|------
1        | 1
1        | 2
1        | 3
2        | 1
2        | 2
1        | 4
```

The `TenantId` and `FooId` would be composite keys. When inserting a new row, I want to be able to run:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (TenantId)
VALUES (2)
```

Which should add the following row

```
TenantId | FooId
---------|------
...      | ...
2        | 3
```

What I actuall get is:

```
TenantId | FooId
---------|------
...      | ...
2        | 4
```

How can I ensure that the `IDENTITY` on `FooId` creates new ID numbers that are in sequence depending on the TenantId? Is that even possible?

Comment: You can do this using a trigger.  Usually, it is quite sufficient to have an overall unique row in the table, not depending on the tenant.

Comment: Is there a way without a trigger?

Comment: Yes, you could add a computed column based on a udt, but that's going to have worst performance than a trigger. Why not just use one identity column for all tenants?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sequence objects, one for each tenant, instead of using an identity column.
However you probably don't need to. Is there a reason why each of the row id's for each tenant have to be seeded from 1 and be sequential?

Comment: The `FooId` is being pulled into a an existing reporting warehouse and I don't want to change the ID's.

Comment: well sequence is probably a way, you would still have to change your insert stmt or add a trigger